# Tinymce Editor Sidebar at Left Side

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I want to show Tinymce Editor slider at the left side

I have used the Tinymce Sidebar API [TinyMCE SideBar](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/creating-a-sidebar/)

Try here [Tinymce SideBar Fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/gEfaab) Sidebar is at right sude but i want that at left side

I tried following but it shows at the right side as follow

[image]

But I want slider at the Right side as follow

[image]

how can i do this Please suggest any plugin

Answer (score 2):

TinyMCE does not currently support opening the standard Sidebar on the left side of the editor.  If you wanted such a capability I would suggest making that suggestion on the GitHub issue tracker:

https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues